# Provide username and password for proxy - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying the below code. But its still giving dialog box for entering username and password when firefox browser starts. Where am I wrong?

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
Proxy firefox_proxy = new Proxy();
firefox_proxy.HttpProxy = proxy;
firefox_proxy.SslProxy = proxy;
profile.SetProxyPreferences(firefox_proxy);

Firefoxdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), profile, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://" + proxy_username + ":" + proxy_password + "@www.xyz.com/");
```

Comment: So did it work ?

Comment: Try to create own extension for Chrome https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758625/4170608

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `https://` instead of `http://` as on some sites the Basic Authentication works on secure network only.

Syntax: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://proxy_username:proxy_password@www.xyz.com/");`

Comment: Did you try doing the same manually. I think if this program doesn't work then it won't work manually as well but give it a try. Or you can share the details with me privately and I'll try it at my end if it's not that confidential.

Comment: The problem is, passing the username and password in the URL is used to pass credentials to the site being accessed as a basic authentication header.  I don't believe it uses those same credentials to authenticate to the proxy.