# C# Selenium Proxy Authentication with Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, proxy-authentication

I am using the following code for the proxy. however, when chrome starts, pop-up window will pop up and the program will be locked.

```
public async void StartDriver(string proxy)
    {
        var proxys = new Proxy();
        ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        bool flag = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy);
        if (flag)
        {
            proxys.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
            proxys.IsAutoDetect = false;
            proxys.SslProxy = proxy;
            chromeOptions.Proxy = proxys;
        }
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
```

I tried http or ssl the same...

```
StartDriver("88.55.66.77:8080");
```

Or

```
StartDriver("http://username:pass@88.55.66.77:8080");
```

I could not start a browser with a kind of proxy.

I want a code that automatically enters the username and password. I don't want autoitx3.dll.

is there a way to start a secure proxy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In 2021 you can use Selenium 4.0 and [BiDi APIs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidi_apis/) for making requests through a proxy with authorization.
Example:

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions {AcceptInsecureCertificates = true};
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.Proxy = new Proxy {HttpProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", SslProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", Kind = ProxyKind.Manual};
//options.AddArguments($"--proxy-server=http://1.1.1.1:12345");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
{
    UriMatcher = d => true, //d.Host.Contains("your-host.com")
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("proxy_user", "proxy_pass")
};

var networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

networkInterceptor.StopMonitoring();
driver.Quit();
```

Comment: Thanks! it finally work!

Comment: Thanks, it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to start a secure proxy?

There's one. You need to create a chrome extension with proxy settings.

**manifest.json**

```json
    {
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "%NAME IT AS YOU WANT%",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
```

**background.js**

```js
//note that it's a JS code. You can use any additional code to do anything :) 
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: "%HOST%",
        port: parseInt(%PORT%)
      },
      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
  };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%USERNAME%",
            password: "%PASSWORD%"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['blocking']
);
```

Pack it as an archive. For instance *yourExt.dat*

```c
var proxy = "yourExt.dat";
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtension(proxy);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This answer is correct but the final part is quite confusing. The packed file is not .dat extension else is just creating a .crx file that you can generate within any Chrome with the above files and options.AddExtension(proxy); only load extensions file in .crx format.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4 has a bug. WebSocket exception during performing basic authorization
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10054